# Shopware Arabic Invoice Text Not Connected

Tags: php, css, pdf, mpdf, shopware

Im Using Shopware to create an arabic online shop and the problem is when shopware is creating the pdf, letters look not connected for example :

ر ق م  ا ل ف ا ت و ر ة

while it should be

رقم الفاتورة

What i have tried so far is using different websafe fonts in the shopware backed body css under PdfCreation, i found that fonts changes but letters are still not connected.

while surfing shopware i found that it uses MPDF library to convert a file called index.tpl (Markup) to pdf , i tried a  pointing to a google font and using it for body but it didn't load the font

[image: Sample Pdf Generated by Shopware (Under PdfCreation Preview )]

Comment: Specifically, your letters are not connected because they have spaces between them.  If you provide the code that you tried then maybe someone will be able to help you.

Comment: i used spaces to demonstrate the issue , anyway it's fixed now , thanks for the tip ! :) @feedMe

Comment: @Ahmed Wessam I'm sorry. My english isn't very good. Tell my please, how I can turn on  PDF Invoice in my shopware 5.2.2?

Comment: @ultimatum what do you mean by turn on ? you can generate PDF invoices for each order under Customers(Tab) > Orders > Click on the pen icon(Show Details) for the order you wish > Documents(Tab) > Preview/Generate as you wish

Comment: @Ahmed Wessam I mean, connect the functional generation of PDF invoice

Comment: @ultimatum please explain what are you trying to achieve, I'm really trying to help

Comment: @Ahmed Wessam I try in shopware 5.2.20 attach 
functional PDF invoice

Comment: @Ahmed Wessam I did. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that ! Good Luck With your project

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Okay after some searching I found that this is a problem with mPdf library as Shopware was using **mPdf 6.0** which had a problem , so i downloaded mPdf 7.0 with composer [Github](https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf/blob/development/CHANGELOG.md) , uploaded to FTP overriding the old mpdf library under `engine/Library/Mpdf/` and it worked!

I hope this helps someone!